# How do i know when the image is loaded and then react on it?

Tags: javascript

I am doing an AJAX call which uses this function when certain criteria are met from the AJAX call it is supposed to show two images.

I create elements with a function, what i do is i add a class while making the elements etc "rightIn" and "leftIn" which are animation classes.. the problem is when the classes are added and the images comes in from left/right the images might not be fully loaded into the source of the image element yet.... which gives a bad effect?

So basically how can i wait and check for when the images have ben loaded and then add the right/left in classes? i tried some different things with `.complete` and load event but dident quite get to where i wanted.

```
function optionTwo(versusOne, versusTwo, versusOneId, versusTwoId) {
    var newElement = createElement("div", {
        "id": "contentVersusWrapper",
        "class": ["contentVersusWrapper"]
    }, contentWrapper);
    var contentVersusWrapper = document.getElementById("contentVersusWrapper");
    var newElement = createElement("div", {
        "id": "contentVersusHelperOne",
        "class": ["contentVersusHelper", "leftIn"]
    }, contentVersusWrapper);
    var contentVersusHelperOne = document.getElementById("contentVersusHelperOne");

    var newDiv = createElement("img", {
        "id": "versusOne",
        "class": ["babeVersus"],
        "src": versusOne
    }, contentVersusHelperOne);
    var newDiv = createElement("input", {
        "id": "versusOneId",
        "class": ["versusOneId"],
        "type": "hidden",
        "name": "versus",
        "value": versusOneId
    }, contentVersusHelperOne);

    var newDiv = createElement("img", {
        "id": "versusIcon",
        "class": ["versusIcon", "scaleIn"],
        "src": "assets/img/versusIcon.png"
    }, contentVersusWrapper);

    var newElement = createElement("div", {
        "id": "contentVersusHelperTwo",
        "class": ["contentVersusHelper", "rightIn"]
    }, contentVersusWrapper);
    var contentVersusHelperTwo = document.getElementById("contentVersusHelperTwo");
    var newDiv = createElement("img", {
        "id": "versusTwo",
        "class": ["babeVersus"],
        "src": versusTwo
    }, contentVersusHelperTwo);
    var versusOne, versusTwo;

    var newDiv = createElement("input", {
        "id": "versusTwoId",
        "class": ["versusTwoId"],
        "type": "hidden",
        "name": "versus",
        "value": versusTwoId
    }, contentVersusHelperTwo);

    document.getElementById("versusOne").addEventListener('click', shuffleContent.bind(null, "versusOne"), false);
    document.getElementById("versusTwo").addEventListener('click', shuffleContent.bind(null, "versusTwo"), false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, putting a `load` event on an `<img>` is a good way to check.

```
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'myurl.png';
img.addEventListener('load', () => console.log('loaded'));
```

However, there is a catch. If the image was loaded previously **it won't trigger the `load` event**.

This can happen if your creating lots of images, with some recurring URLs.

You can however check for that by checking the `width` or `height` of the image. An image that hasn't loaded will always have a width and height of 0. If it's anything other than zero, it's loaded.

```
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'myimage.png';
img.addEventListener('load', onLoadFunc);

if (img.width) {
  onLoadFunc();
}
```

This will ensure that you catch both methods to ensure it's loaded.

Assuming that your `createElement` returned an `Image` element (the same thing that comes out of `document.createElement('img')`, then your code would probably look something like this:

```
var newDiv = createElement("img", {
    "id": "versusIcon",
    "class": ["versusIcon", "scaleIn"],
    "src": "assets/img/versusIcon.png"
}, contentVersusWrapper);
newDiv.addEventListener('load', doSomething);

if(newDiv.width) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Where `doSomething()` is a function that does whatever you need it to do when the image is loaded.

Comment: But the images will be loaded more than once, its a rating versus system so the same images can be loaded again and again.. also how do i implement this is my javascript

Comment: @Javaish Indeed, which is why I gave you the extra bit, because I figured you were reloading images multiple times. That's why you should also text `img.width`. As for how to implement it in your specific JavaScript, I can't tell you because I don't know what your `createElement` function is returning. Basically though, wherever you specify `src`, set the event listener and do the width check, and then call your callback if either pass.

Comment: `function createElement(type, attributes, someElement) {
        var element = document.createElement(type);
        for (var key in attributes) {
            if (key === "class") {
                var cls = attributes[key];
                for (var c in cls)
                    element.classList.add(cls[c]);
            } else {
                element[key] = attributes[key];
            }
        }
        someElement.appendChild(element);
    }`

Comment: Well basically this is the create function that i use

But i dont see how i can use this with my function and append the left/right in css animation to their parent element when the images are loaded :)

Comment: I added an update to my answer to try and point you in the right direction. Take a stab at it, and if you still have issues, post a new question with your updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the image up to have a "load" event callback function:

```js
var img = document.querySelector("img");

img.addEventListener("load", function(){
  alert("image loaded");
  img.classList.add("loaded");
});
```

```css
.loaded { border:4px solid red; }
```

```html
<img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/hubble_share.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the jquery data store you can define a 'loaded' state.

```js
if ($('#image').data('loaded')) {
    // loaded, so do stuff
}
```

```html
<img id="image" onload="$(this).data('loaded', 'loaded');" src="" />
```

Comment: I do not use jQery the question is also not marked with jQuery :)